# Get last occurrence using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a huge string with this inside:

```
linha[0] = '12/2010    281R$          272.139,05                            ';
linha[0] = '13SL         1R$          226.185,81                            ';
```

Both lines are separate, and I need get the last occurrence from both. I'm using the following regex to match the first one:

```
/linha\[0]\s=\s'(.*)';/
```

I would like to get the second "linha..." too, but I don't know exactly how.

That's how i'm using this regex to get the first "linha...":

```
string.match(/linha\[0]\s=\s'(.*)';/);
```

output:

```
linha[0] = '12/2010    281R$          272.139,05                            ';
```

Also, i can't do extra work, i need get the second occurrence using only regex.

Comment: Why not `hugeString.match(/linha\[0]\s=\s'([^']*)';/g).pop()` ? Note that if you need to extract the submach, you'll have to use [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Comment: Please specify the question yet it is ambiguous to understand

Comment: so, what expected output?

Comment: What you mean by second one?

Comment: I'm sorry, the question is not clear. Just a second.

Comment: I expanded my comment into an answer for a greater clarity.

Comment: the second is always the last, so both? hahaha

Comment: I that case `/linha\[0]\s*=\s*'(.*?)';$/` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the last occurrence of your regex in a string (and assuming it exists), you can do

```
var str = hugeString.match(/linha\[0]\s=\s'([^']*)';/g).pop();
```

(yes, I changed `.*` to `[^']*` for a better efficiency, ignore that if you have quotes in your inner string)

Now, if you want to extract just the submatch, you can do

```
var regex = /linha\[0]\s=\s'([^']*)';/g,
    arr,
    str;
while (arr = regex.exec(hugeString)) str = arr[1];
```

Comment: isn't possible match the second one only using regex, without extra work?

Comment: @FátimaAlves You could use a `$` anchor (assuming it's at the end of the string)... `linha\[0]\s=\s'(.*)';$` - https://regex101.com/r/nF6aE0/1